# Java: Remove Object from List using equals override

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

Note: I have to use Java 8
I'm trying to remove and add objects from a Java `ArrayList` like this:

```
private List<Point> points;

[...]

void addPoint(int x, int y) {
    Point newpoint = new Point(x, y);
    if (!points.contains(newpoint)) {
        points.add(new Point(x, y));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error! Point already exists!");
    }
}

void removePoint(int x, int y) {
    Point newpoint = new Point(x, y);
    if (points.removeIf(n -> n.equals(newpoint))) {
        System.out.println("Point was removed!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error! Point does not exist!");
    }
}
```

`Point` is a simple object with a `x` and `y` `int` and a `equals` method, which return `true` if the supplied `Point` Object has the same coordinates.

As you can see I'm checking if an object exists and then add it, and in `removePoint` I use `removeIf` (which i think is suboptimal) to remove the point from the list.
So how do I correctly tackle this problem by overriding the `equals` method and is `removeIf` truly suboptimal?

Comment: `removeIf` is the most efficient way of doing the removal, if you expect there to be multiple occurrences. If you expect there to be at most 1, use `remove`.

Comment: "and a equals method" I hope you've overridden `hashCode` too.

Comment: Do you really need `points` to be a `List` or could you use a `Set` instead ? For this use case, a `HashSet` seems neat.

Comment: Are you sure, you are not looking for an ordered `Set` instead? What exactly is the query to read this data?

Comment: If you need to maintain the insertion order of the elements then you should use `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: I have to use some specific things like a list, as this is an exercise for university. As it turns out, only a linear running time for this part is required, but i will optimize the code with the stated methods when i find free time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could override the EqualsAndHashCode Method, or add a method to your Point.class which compares an given coordinates like

```
public boolean sameCoordinates(Point point){
  return this.x-point.getX()==0 && this.y-point.getY()==0
}
```

I used removeIf in a previous project, but we substitued it with streams. One reason was, that removeIf works on a given list, and Java works with call by reference. This forced us to copy lists in each method which works on this list before we call removeIf otherwise we would changed it throuh the programm.

An other reason was, that removeIf on an HashSet will change the Set, which means it changes the HashCode. Java safe anywhere the hash value of this set. If you want to use this set later you will get an error since Java doesn´t know the new hash value only the old one. This took us some time to find the root of this error.

Here a small example how to use streams

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
    numberList.add(1);
    numberList.add(2);
    numberList.add(3);
    numberList.add(4);
    numberList.add(5);
    numberList.add(6);

    List<Integer> evenNumbers = numberList.stream().filter(number -> number % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(evenNumbers);
```

To sum it up, I use streams. I hope this helps you a bit.